# Can we do form post redirection with AWS Lambdas and API Gateway

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So now I need to do a form post to an OIDC implicit flow authorize endpoint from api gateway and lambda. I had google around and found out the only way from online is to do set http status code 301/302 and set Location in response header for lambda response and api gateway will do the redirection based on the status code, but I found out this workaround will only trigger HTTP GET.

So I want to know whether there's any other workaround can achieve something like do a form post redirection through aws api gateway and aws lambdas. Or the tech stack that I use is impossible to achieve this scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us help you, can you please provide more info? The question is unclear. Why won't a GET work for you? What are you looking to do? What's the issue?